# Dojo: How to disable a TabBarButton?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojo, dojox.mobile

How can I disable a TabBarButton?
I want it to be unclickable and gray.

There isn't any parameter to set it in the guide.
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/TabBarButton.html

```
    createFooter : function() {

       this.inherited(arguments);

       this.footer = new Footer({}, this.footerNode);

       this.settingsBtn = new TabBarButton(
         {
          clickable:false,
          icon : "images/settingsIcon.png",
         }, domConstruct.create("li"));

       this.footer.addChild(this.settingsBtn);

       this.settingsBtn.onClick = lang.hitch(this, "settings");

      },

      settings : function() {

       alert("settings started");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created my own widget, because this wasn't default functionality of a tabbarButton.
Here is my code:

```
    define([
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/dom-class",
        "dojox/mobile/TabBarButton"
    ], function(declare, lang, on, domClass, TabBarButton) {
        return declare("TabBarButtonDisable",[TabBarButton], {

            onClickBackup:null,
            isDisabled : false,


            _setIsDisabledAttr : function(isDisabled) {
                this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
                this.renderIsDisabled();
            },
            _getIsDisabledAttr : function() {
                return this.isDisabled;
            },

            renderIsDisabled : function() {
                if (this.isDisabled) {
                    domClass.add(this.domNode, "disabled");
                    this.onClick = function(){
                // isDisabled
                    };
                } else {
                    domClass.remove(this.domNode, "disabled");
                    this.onClick = this.onClickBackup;
                }
            },

            buildRendering : function() {
                this.inherited(arguments);
                this.onClickBackup = this.onClick;
            },

            postCreate: function() {
                this.inherited(arguments);
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set clickable to false. It is a parameter in the parent _itembase.

Your link of document may out of date, you can find this parameter at _itembase sourcecode.

Comment: The documentation of itembase doesn't say if you set clickable on false the widget's onclick won't work. If set on true, the item becomes clickable even if a transition destination (moveTo, etc.) is not specified.

If I set clickable to false, I still can click it. (I linked a lang.hitch to the item)

Comment: Can you try onclick instead of onClick, see [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/ykami/entry/dojo_mobile_onclick_handlers11?lang=en)